# Multiple videos can not play on each device

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am confused about playing 3 videos at the same time. I have an activity with 3 fragments. Each fragment play a video. When I play 3 videos simultaneously my LG Nexus 5 shows in few seconds but then hanged. I have read all the solution stuff regarding playing Multiple videos depend on the hardware. But on the other hand in Skype every device shows multiple videos in group call.

```
public void playVideo(final String path) {
mVideoView = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
mVideoView.start();}
```

Your suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Good question :),  do you have the <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...> in your AndroidManifest.xml right?

Comment: @yes jos I did that but it did not work.

Comment: I think there is problem with the fragments. It works when a remove fragments from the activity. I mean in a activity three videoview .